# Find the earliest date and assign hours

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My initial dataframe looks as follows:

| ID | EarliestStart | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 28.09.2023 | 15,00 |
| 2 | 29.09.2023 | 5,00 |
| 3 | 15.11.2023 | 23,00 |

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 2, 3],
    'EarliestStart': ['28.09.2023', '29.09.2023', '15.11.2023'],
    'Hours': [15.00, 5.00, 23.00]
})

df['EarliestStart'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EarliestStart'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
```

I would like to achieve a dataframe that looks something like this:

| ID | EarliestStart | PlannedStart | Weekday | HoursSplitted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 28.09.2023 | 28.09.2023 | Thursday | 7,00 |
| 1 | 28.09.2023 | 29.09.2023 | Friday | 7,00 |
| 1 | 28.09.2023 | 02.10.2023 | Monday | 1,00 |
| 2 | 29.09.2023 | 02.10.2023 | Monday | 5,00 |
| 3 | 15.11.2023 | 15.11.2023 | Wednesday | 7,00 |
| 3 | 15.11.2023 | 16.11.2023 | Thursday | 7,00 |
| 3 | 15.11.2023 | 17.11.2023 | Friday | 7,00 |
| 3 | 15.11.2023 | 20.11.2023 | Monday | 2,00 |

A maximum of 7 hours can be allocated per day/date. This means the IDs are **not** independent.
ID 2 could theoretically start on the 29.09.2029 but there is already an entry before which allocates all 7 hours on this day. Therefor it should be shifted to next available spot.

Also no weekends (saturday/sunday) are allowed. Is there an elegant way to achieve this? To be honest, I don't know in which order I should carry out the operations to get the final dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

You can [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) the rows based on the ceiled division by the hours per day, then add [`BusinessDay`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay.html) offset multiplied by [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
# repeat the rows
out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(np.ceil(df['Hours'].div(7)))]

# increment the days
n = out.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
out['PlannedStart'] = pd.to_datetime(out['EarliestStart']
                                    +n*pd.offsets.BusinessDay())

# get day name
out['Weekday'] = out['PlannedStart'].dt.day_name()

# fix last split per group if needed
s = out.pop('Hours').mod(7)
out['HoursSplitted'] = np.where(out.index.duplicated(keep='last') | s.eq(0),
                                7, s)
```

Output:

```
   ID EarliestStart PlannedStart    Weekday  HoursSplitted
0   1    2023-09-28   2023-09-28   Thursday            7.0
0   1    2023-09-28   2023-09-29     Friday            7.0
0   1    2023-09-28   2023-10-02     Monday            1.0
1   2    2023-09-29   2023-09-29     Friday            5.0
2   3    2023-11-15   2023-11-15  Wednesday            7.0
2   3    2023-11-15   2023-11-16   Thursday            7.0
2   3    2023-11-15   2023-11-17     Friday            7.0
2   3    2023-11-15   2023-11-20     Monday            2.0
```

Comment: ID 2 is not allowed to start also on 2023-09-29 because per day/date only 7 hours are possible.

Comment: @question12 why not? `2023-09-29` is a Friday

Comment: Because there is already another entry on this date:
1    2023-09-28   2023-09-29     Friday            7.0

Comment: @question12 do you mean that the IDs are **not** independent? That is not clear at all from the question, please update.

Comment: @mozway I got the impression that there was a max of 7 hours of work per day, so in this case it would shift forwards onto the Monday

Comment: @Mark I thought this was per ID, not across IDs. Then the logic should be updated. I don't see a straightforward approach though, I believe a loop might be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Until some wizard comes in with a one-liner you could just define a function to do it manually:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 2, 3],
    'EarliestStart': ['28.09.2023', '29.09.2023', '15.11.2023'],
    'Hours': [15.00, 5.00, 23.00]
})
df['EarliestStart'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EarliestStart'], format='%d.%m.%Y')

def split_hours(row):
    id = row['ID']
    start_date = row['EarliestStart']
    hours = row['Hours']
    hours_per_day = 7
    results = []
    while hours > 0:
        # If the day is weekend, skip to next day
        while start_date.weekday() in [5, 6]:  # 5 = Saturday, 6 = Sunday
            start_date += timedelta(days=1)
        hours_today = min(hours_per_day, hours)
        results.append({
            'ID': id,
            'EarliestStart': row['EarliestStart'],
            'PlannedStart': start_date,
            'Weekday': start_date.strftime('%A'),
            'HoursSplitted': hours_today
        })
        hours -= hours_today
        start_date += timedelta(days=1)
    return results

rows = df.apply(split_hours, axis=1)
flat_list = [item for sublist in rows for item in sublist]
result_df = pd.DataFrame(flat_list)
result_df['EarliestStart'] = result_df['EarliestStart'].dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
result_df['PlannedStart'] = result_df['PlannedStart'].dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
result_df
```

**Output:**

| ID | EarliestStart | PlannedStart | Weekday | HoursSplitted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 28.09.2023 | 28.09.2023 | Thursday | 7.0 |
| 1 | 28.09.2023 | 29.09.2023 | Friday | 7.0 |
| 1 | 28.09.2023 | 02.10.2023 | Monday | 1.0 |
| 2 | 29.09.2023 | 29.09.2023 | Friday | 5.0 |
| 3 | 15.11.2023 | 15.11.2023 | Wednesday | 7.0 |
| 3 | 15.11.2023 | 16.11.2023 | Thursday | 7.0 |
| 3 | 15.11.2023 | 17.11.2023 | Friday | 7.0 |
| 3 | 15.11.2023 | 20.11.2023 | Monday | 2.0 |

Comment: I think this is quite wizard like :D
Did you do this with the help of chatGPT or completely by yourself within this time? Really nice, I have to check each line..
ID 2 is not allowed to be on 29th because there are already 7 hours allocated to this day.

Comment: hasn't `append()` been deprecated? :S

Answer (score 0):

Use `timedelta`  from the pandas library.

- make a function to add the days, simply to get the next day for the next 7 hour chunk.
- slit hours using a for loop, loop through each row, breaking down the Hours into 7-hour chunks, creating a new entry.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 2, 3],
    'EarliestStart': pd.to_datetime(['28.09.2023', '29.09.2023', '15.11.2023'], format='%d.%m.%Y'),
    'Hours': [15.00, 5.00, 23.00]
})

# Track the hours that are already allocated for the day 
hours_allocated_per_day = defaultdict(float)

def next_avail_date(start_date, allocated_hours):
    current_date = start_date
    while True:
        if current_date.weekday() >= 5 or allocated_hours[current_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')] >= 7:
            current_date += timedelta(days=1)
        else:
            break
    return current_date

rows_list = []

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    hours_left = row['Hours']
    current_date = row['EarliestStart']
    while hours_left > 0:
        current_date = next_avail_date(current_date, hours_allocated_per_day)
        hours_for_day = min(7 - hours_allocated_per_day[current_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')], hours_left)

        rows_list.append({
            'ID': row['ID'],
            'EarliestStart': row['EarliestStart'].strftime('%d.%m.%Y'),
            'PlannedStart': current_date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y'),
            'Weekday': current_date.strftime('%A'),
            'HoursSplitted': hours_for_day
        })

        # Update allocated hours for the current date
        hours_allocated_per_day[current_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')] += hours_for_day
        hours_left -= hours_for_day

        if hours_allocated_per_day[current_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')] >= 7:
            current_date += timedelta(days=1)

adjusted_final_df = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)

adjusted_final_df
```

Comment: `add_days_skip()` is not defined! :S

Comment: this also doesn't give the right days sadly

Comment: missed it. I think i need another structure to track the allocated hours given that 29-09 was allocated hours from 28-09.

Comment: adjusted to track the hours allocated for each day.